# How to hide keyboard automatically after sending e-mail using emailIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, keyboard, message

There is a page where the user can send e-mail, sms or call its guests when needed. The problem is that when the user sends e-mail to its guest, the keyboard doesn't hide. Even-though I have a small problem solving the issue, It still seems hard to find alike post to solve it. I'll be also making screenshots and placing them in here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the keyboard doesn't hide after sending mail.

Comment: anything new here?, i'm having the same defect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                    new String[] { **EmailAddress** });
                            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1);




   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
        super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(**AnyViewOfScreen**.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, I used the code in onResume method and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy just add the following code in your manifest for the desire activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution, +1

Answer (score 3):

Its not the to override when the keyboard shows and hides itself, but here are the two methods I use to hide and show the keyboard as needed.

```
    public void hideKeyboard(final View aView){
                 aView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){

                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                     }
                 }
    }
    public void showKeyboard(final View aView) {
        aView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(ListingScreen.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

When you call hide/show Keyboard, pass in your current view. The post runnable thread will wait to run until the view has finished loading, then dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: I have used your hideKeyboard() method in the onCreate and after the email intent. The problem is that it doesn't work. The keyboard still seems to be active after sending an e-mail.

Comment: Try putting it in a postRunnable thread. I will edit my code for an example

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps someone :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("OnResume", "Called");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) LocationDetailActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }, 300);

}
```

if you do not have any focusable view in your layout, just add a dummy linear layout to your xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call This method at the place where you want to hide your keyboard if it is opened(e.g call this when you click to sendingEmail button)

```
protected void showVirturalKeyboard()
{

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if(m != null)
            {
                m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Nope I don't think that there is any way to solve the issue here. I need to have access to the Gmail app to hide the keyboard after the e-mail has been sended.

Answer (score 0):

After trying every solution I found on StackOverflow nothing seemed to worked. In the end I did find a way to force close the keyboard, but it is not ideal.

You can set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the Android Manifest for that activity.

The unfortunate side effect of this is explained here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft :

"The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window."

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem. Gmail hides the keyboard after sending. When you return to your application it focuses on something else. If you take slower device you'll see that gmail hides keyboard after sending message.